# Android Values won't insert in the database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having problem in storing data in my database. This is the method for inserting text values to database:

```
private void openVerify() {
    HashMap <String, String> queryValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
    queryValues.put("UserEmail", txtNewEmail.getText().toString());
    queryValues.put("FirstName", txtNewFirstName.getText().toString());
    queryValues.put("LastName", txtNewLastName.getText().toString());
    queryValues.put("Password", txtNewPassword.getText().toString());
    queryValues.put("PhoneNo", txtNewPhoneNumber.getText().toString());
    queryValues.put("Address", txtNewAddress.getText().toString());
    int success = (int)db.insertCustomer(queryValues);

    if (success > 0)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Code has been sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        openVerification();
        finish();

}
```

This is the SQL of inserting data from the method above which is in another class:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE tblUsers (UserID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, UserEmail TEXT" +
            "FirstName TEXT, LastName TEXT, Password TEXT, PhoneNo TEXT, Address TEXT) ";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

public int insertCustomer(HashMap<String, String> queryValues){

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("UserEmail",queryValues.get("UserEmail"));
    values.put("FirstName",queryValues.get("FirstName"));
    values.put("LastName",queryValues.get("LastName"));
    values.put("Password",queryValues.get("Password"));
    values.put("PhoneNo",queryValues.get("PhoneNo"));
    values.put("Address",queryValues.get("Address"));

    int success = (int) database.insert("tblUsers", null, values);
    database.close();
    return success;
}
```

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: Why the mysql tag? Do you get any exception?

Comment: Sorry accidentally clicked it when it shows up as recommended. No, I didn't get any exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE tblUsers (UserID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, UserEmail TEXT," +
        "FirstName TEXT, LastName TEXT, Password TEXT, PhoneNo TEXT, Address TEXT) ";
```

Did you miss a comma after **UserEmail TEXT**?

Comment: I tried putting it but it didn't work? Do I need to drop the database first?

Comment: I assume that the OnCreate() is within your own customized SQLiteOpenHelper class, and you have debug/run your App for at least one time without problem. So, at this point of time, your App will not trigger the OnCreate() method. In order to trigger the OnCreate() method, either you uninstall & install the App or perform "Clear Data" on the App.